# cant install WineHQ on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wine

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 which is 64bit, when I try install Wine from WineHQ or Ubuntu repository this happen

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.0.0~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and afterwards when I try to install wine-stable first this happen

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgd3:i386 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and if I try to install `libgd3:i386`, yes, it would install `winehq-stable` then gnome control center is gone, which is my desktop settings, and also `php-gd` is gone too, and reinstalling `libgd3` will remove Wine32 which make Wine inoperateable

I did add the architecture though

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

how am I supposed to solve this?

Comment: sadly no, I did `dpkg --add-architecture i386` thus add `i386` when you run `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` as I mention before. but, `apt update` and `apt upgrade` doesn't change anything. for now my conclusion is just using Bottles instead

Comment: is installing Bottles can be counted as an answer? because my questions is installing Wine, even though I know that Bottles using Wine but in sandbox mode

Comment: Did you try `apt --fix-broken install` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install libpcre3:amd64=2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1 libpcre3:i386=2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1

sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```